# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric - SQL Server

Tags: html, decimal, overflow, numeric

I have a column with datatype `numeric(18,3)`. The user can enter decimal numbers as well. I have set the max length of this text box to 18 but when I type 777777777777777777, I get this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

Can someone explain me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please include the actual SQL code which generated this error.

Comment: Because `numeric(18,3)` means: **18** digits in **total**, thereof **3** after the decimal point - so you only get **15 digits** before the decimal point. Entering **18** digits (before the decimal point) will obviously cause an overflow ! If you really **need** 18 digits before the decimal point, you need to define your column as `numeric(21,3)` .... - [read the fabulous docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN MinimumValue numeric(18,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `numeric(18,3)` means: **18** digits in **total**, thereof **3** after the decimal point - so you only get **15 digits** before the decimal point.

Entering **18** digits (before the decimal point) will obviously cause an overflow!

If you really **need** 18 digits before the decimal point, you need to define your column as `numeric(21,3)`

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName 
    ALTER COLUMN MinimumValue NUMERIC(21, 3)
```

For more details, [read the fabulous docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Or I can add maxlength attribut and set it to 15 so it does not allow user to enter more than this? @marc_s